# Set device owner app causes "Workspace has been locked" on Android 8.1 Oreo

Tags: samsung, 8.1-oreo, device-administrator, work-profiles

I've been using my app as a device owner app since Android Lollipop.
I have a new device here which I want to be a device owner too. It is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.5(2018) SM-T590. I am currently running this version of the ROM: T590XXU2ASC1.

I am not using the NFC method. I usually create the `/data/system/device_owner.xml` file by myself. But since it is not working, I tried this method:

1. Factory reset the tablet in recovery mode
2. Pass through the annoying startup menus
3. Set lock screen to none
4. Enable USB Debugging
5. Install my app `adb install MyApplicaton.apk`
6. `adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.myapplication/.MyApplicationReceiver`. It always says success when I execute the command.
7. Start my app, I can pin/unpin my app without problem.
8. Reboot, and then the famous message appears every time:

   [image]

   > Workspace has been locked
   > Unauthorized software has been installed on your device. Workspace has been locked to prevent any unauthorized access. Contact your admin.

Then if I press on the FACTORY DATA RESET button, the workspace app crashes then pops back.

I tried the kioskModeDemo app and the androidDeviceOwner sample app and they all do the same problem.

Does anybody have any hints of why this is not working anymore on Android 8 Oreo?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: once you OEM unlock (custom OS) your device on a certain Samsung Knox level API, you can't be the device owner anymore on this device.

This is from [Samsung Knox page](https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/knox-and-nfc-device-owner-provisioning):

> "Cannot create work profile" "The security policy prevents the creation of a managed device because a custom OS is or has been installed on this device".

The device could be vulnerable to potential attacks with custom OS.